# which file format to use for the ios app tutorial which should be embedded inside the app?

Tags: video-recording, ios

we have developed ios application, and now stacked at tutorial preparations , google does not helped too much.
Our issue is the following : what format will allow us to have the most size-wise optimised solution? What is the golden standard used for videos inside ios apps?
There is a really lack of resources about that....

Answer (score 1):

The videos I've delivered for iOS App *Previews* have been as per the specification in this [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW6), viz. H.264 video codec, Baseline profile, 30 fps, AAC-LC audio codec, sampling rate 48 kHz, stereo in MP4 or MOV. Resolution and bitrate haven't been restricted to what the docs say. Those should be tailored to the device(s) your app is for.